# SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I got this error message after running my SSIS package with job, sometimes running this task manually completes successfully.

```
Error : 2014-12-01 06:28:44.37
   Code : 0x00000000
   Source : SQL Server Analysis Services Processing Task
   Message :
Fin de l'erreur
Warning : 2014-12-01 06:28:46.62
   Code : 0x80019002
   Source : Package
Message: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method 
succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. 
This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. 
Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

Fin de l'avertissement
DTExec : l'exécution du package a retourné DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Démarré : 05:00:01
Terminé : 06:28:57
Écoulé :  5334.95 secondes
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old entry here but for those who may have similar issue. I had exactly same problem. SSIS was completing successfully(all steps were green) although it was still popping up an error.

In my case, I had some disabled tasks(steps) which had some errors. I think that although they were disabled and will not be executed, SSIS still verifies them and returns error and under the `"Progress"` tab, it doesn't display extended error information. It only returns this message in the question.

But exact question can be observed using the `"Log Events"` window which can be found under `"SSIS->Log Events"` menu on top of Visual Studio 2015. There you can see `"Name"` with `"OnError"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141212(v=sql.105).aspx
You can enable logging to a SQL table for your runtime SSIS packages, and see what is actually causing the error.

Comment: Error : The following system error occurred:  Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. .
Error : Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'DW', Name of 'DW'.

Comment: the Analysis Services Processing Task doesn't works since the changing of the password of administrator account user.